# How do I display a tooltip for a CMFCRibbonButton in the status bar?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, ribbon, tooltip, mfc-feature-pack

I have a `CMFCRibbonStatusBar` in my mainframe to which I add a `CMFCRibbonButtonsGroup` which again has a `CMFCRibbonButton`. This button has the same ID as a menu entry.

Creating the button is done as follows:

```
CMFCRibbonButtonsGroup* pBGroup = new CMFCRibbonButtonsGroup();

CMFCToolBarImages images;
images.SetImageSize(CSize(32, 16)); // Non-square bitmaps
if(images.Load(IDB_STATUSBAR_IMAGES))
{
    pBGroup->SetImages(&images, NULL, NULL);
}

m_pStatusButton = new CMFCRibbonButton(ID_STATUS_SHOWSTATUS,
                                       _T(""),
                                       IMAGEINDEX_DEFAULTSTATUS);

pBGroup->AddButton(m_pStatusButton);

m_wndStatusBar.AddExtendedElement(pBGroup, _T(""));
```

I want to use this button as a status indicator.

I want to display a tool tip in the following two cases:

- when the status changes and
- when the user moves the mouse over the button.

I have no idea how to start in the first place. I have looked at the `ToolTipDemo` and `DlgToolTips` sample projects but couldn't figure out how to do it since all they do is display tooltips for the toolbar items or dialog buttons (`CWnd`-derived instead of `CMFCRibbonButton`).

If you are familiar with the `ToolTipDemo` sample project: Since there seem to be several ways of doing things, I would prefer the tooltip to look like the "Extended Visual Manager-based" tool tip as [shown in this screenshot](http://img394.imageshack.us/my.php?image=tooltiptm7.png).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to show the tooltip without the mouse cursor being over the control. That's all done automatically.

However if you want to have a nice looking tooltip like in your screenshot, you need to call `SetToolTipText` and `SetDescription`, like this:

```
CMFCRibbonButton* pBtn = new CMFCRibbonButton(12345, _T(""), 1);
pBtn->SetToolTipText("This is the bold Title");
pBtn->SetDescription("This is the not-so-bold Description");
pGroup->AddButton(pBtn);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using `CMFCRibbonButton` controls within a `CMFCRibbonButtonGroup`, which is added to the `CMFCRibbonStatusBar`.  Take note of the 4th parameter in the `CMFCRibbonButton()` constructor, `bAlwaysShowDescription`, as this seems to affect the behavior depending upon whether `SetDescription()` has been called.

Specifically, if `SetDescription()` has not been called, it doesn't matter whether `bAlwaysShowDescription` is TRUE or FALSE - the tool tip is displayed (as I would expect).  If `SetDescription()` is set and `bAlwaysShowDescription` is FALSE, when hovering over the button the tool tip is displayed with the description below it.

What seems counterintuitive given the name of this `bAlwaysShowDescription` parameter, is that when this is TRUE and `SetDescription()` is set, **NEITHER** the tool tip nor the description appear.  I wonder if this is related to this post:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/399646/cmfcribbonbutton-wont-show-tooltip-if-balwaysshowdescription-1

Hope this helps and you can achieve what you need with the different combinations of `bAlwaysShowDescription` parameter and whether `SetDescription()` is set.